# Auto-layout fails on Project Converted from Xcode 8 to Xcode 9

Tags: autolayout, xcode9, swift4

I had an app working in Xcode 8. After importing it to Xcode 9, autolayout fails.
Multi-line UILabels only showing 1 line. Multi-line UIlabels in the UITableView also show 1 line. I have no constraint issues.

I used something like

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
```

When I implemented a solution as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/36422189#36422189) in the converted project, **auto layout failed**.

But **IF** I create a new project in Xcode 9 and implement the same solution as given in link above, **auto layout works!**

Has anyone encountered such an issue? Is there a way to fix my auto-layout in converted project without re-doing all?

### Edit

It looks like someone is facing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46621966/upgraded-to-xcode-9-swift-4-now-auto-layout-is-whacked).

### Edit 2017.10.18

A possible solution, somewhat hack-ish; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281897/autoresizing-not-working-in-ios11-xcode-9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I found the answer from the following post; https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545177/1179312

What happened prior upgrade to XCode9, I did override `intrinsicContentSize` in an extension to UILabel. **I decided NOT to use this but forgot to remove it from my project.** Then I upgraded to XCode 9 and confused me a lot.

This led to unpredictable behaviour. The fault was mine. Removing the function was previously overriding `intrinsicContentSize` fixed the following;

- autolayout issue
- multiline label issue